# MySQL case sensitivity for primary key

Tags: mysql, collation, case-sensitive

Are MySQL primary key values case sensitive?  If it's an option how do I set it?  I want the table to be able to store "www.Example.com" and "www.example.com" as different values.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Well its giving me a duplicate primary key error but I am inserting into the table multiple times in one query. So I believe that its sees the two entries as the same. This is what I need to know how to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set per-column collations in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html

e.g. if your table is generally (say) case insensitive, you can override it per-field to be case-sensitive.

Comment: So do I understand it correctly that "utf8_general_ci" would most likely mean that it is case insensitive? if thats true I should use a binary collation?

Comment: yes. ci is case insensitive. but there's `utf8_general_cs` for case sensitive.

Comment: I am getting `Unknown collation: 'utf8_general_cs'`. Is this an issue with the version of MySQL I am using? (5.1)

Comment: As per https://serverfault.com/a/137466 the simplest solution is to use `utf8_bin` for case sensitivy.

Answer (score 4):

The `BINARY` keyword will do the trick, though I'm not sure if it's the recommended way to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE testpk (MyPK VARCHAR(20) BINARY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have case-sensitive Unicode collations, [...](https://serverfault.com/a/137466)
So the simplest trick you have is using collation `utf8_bin`.